# JSENCODE Returning Id rather than Name

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am using JSENCODE in a custom button to populate a Contact lookup field on a new Opportunity record from a custom Javascript button. However, the field gets populated with the 15 character ID rather than the Contact's name.  I've tried Contact.Name and Contact__r.Name, and both returns errors.  Any idea how I can get the Contact's Name instead of the ID?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function')
{
srcUp('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!JSENCODE(TEXT(Case.Contact.Name))}&ent=Opportunity');
}
else
{
window.open('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!JSENCODE(TEXT(Case.Contact.Name))}&ent=Opportunity');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious, the code below fixes the issue I was trying to solve:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}

var query = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id = '{!Case.ContactId}' limit 1";

var CName = sforce.connection.query(query);

ConName = CName.getArray("records");
console.log('###'+ConName);
var myCon1 = ConName[0].FirstName;
var myCon2 = ConName[0].LastName;

if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function')
{
srcUp('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!JSENCODE(Case.Contact_Text__c)}&ent=Opportunity');
}
else
{
window.open('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W='+myCon1+' '+myCon2+'&ent=Opportunity');
}
```

I queried the Name of the record I was trying to pull in as text.

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than just a code dump. Also, if implementing a formula field was the solution, your answer doesn't really help others in the same quandary unless you also share the formula.

Comment: I didn't use a formula field

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add explanation. Right now this post is pretty much just a code dump, making it rather low quality.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge in the name, you need to merge in the `Name` field.

```
{!JSENCODE(Case.Contact.Name)}
```

Make sure you add this field to your query.

Comment: When I try that, it tells me Case.Contact.Name does not exist.

Comment: @JohnNeilan This is why you should provide complete context when you *ask* the question...

Comment: Sorry, posted too quickly

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get the name of a lookup field rather than the ID using JSENCODE?

Comment: It has nothing to do with that function. It's the JS button context which matters...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the `JSENCODE` function... whether or not you encode the value is *completely* irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

No need to use JSENCODE function or query the name value.

Just use double quote (") instead of single quote (') in URL like below, it should work.

```
if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function')
{
    srcUp("/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!JSENCODE(TEXT(Case.Contact.Name))}&ent=Opportunity");
}else
{
    window.open("/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!JSENCODE(TEXT(Case.Contact.Name))}&ent=Opportunity");
}
```

Comment: Actually, you need JSENCODE to prevent from all kinds of JS attacks. Not because of the quotes.